# SSH client side port

Tags: ssh, port, client-side

I have a very basic question in mind. When using SSH for connecting to a server, we usually connect using port 22. The server receives requests from the client through this port. My question is when the client receives data from the server (e.g. list of files in a directory) what port is used on the client's side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is only one connection that is bi-directional.

- The port on the server side is 22 (the client needs a known port to connect to the server)
- The port on the client side is dynamic/random, although it will stay the same for the entire SSH session.

Comment: Is there a reference for your point #2? How/where/what defines the range of client-side port numbers?